# How to push comma-separated string into a specific array field?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In javascript, I'm aware that split function can create an array of elements from a comma-separated string like this:

```
var ids = '5f6ac,9bc1d';
var idsArr = ids.split(',');
console.log("output array: " + idsArr); // output array: ["5f6ac","9bc1d"]
```

Given the same comma-separated string, how can I push those elements into a specific field name (i.e. "_id") into the array?

```
var ids = '5f6ac,9bc1d';


Expected output array: [{ _id: "5f6ac" }, { _id: "9bc1d" }];
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
const result = "5f6ac,9bc1d".split(",").map(id => ({ _id: id }));

console.log(result);
```

You already have an array from the split string, all you have to do is convert each number into an object of `{_id: id}` using Array `map` operator.